# cProfile.run function calls vs complexity

Tags: python, performance, complexity-theory, function-calls

When I call `cProfile.run('myFunction1')` it returns with a number of function calls.

I would like to compare various versions of myFunction and find the most effective one(e.g. with the least complexity).

What is the connection between the `function calls` and the `complexity`?

What do the function calls describe?

If I have two functions, is the function with the least number of function calls the most efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of function calls is exactly what is means: number of (sub-)function calls.
There's no strict correlation between func calls and complexity.
To find the most **efficient** implementation you should try mapping your function against different argument sets and timing it. Using the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Calculating the complexity of a function is a too wide argument for a single answer. It depends on the algorithm itself and the complexity of the subfunctions it calls.

Here for more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms